# How Does This Background Image Work?

Tags: html, css, static, background, background-image

So This website:

http://www.atomicdust.com/

They have a background image on every page but when zooming, it doesn't change - ever. Not to mention how fast it loads. How is that possible to have content zoom without the background image? I could understand if it was a repeated image but this is not.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/resize-test.js"></script>` :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On that site it looks as though it's done by a script, as @rownage observes, but I've done it successfully in modern browsers using the (CSS3) "cover" property, i.e. `background-size: cover;` According to my notes (hurrah for comments!) [this A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/) is where I got my information from.

On my (very much still-in-progress!) photo site, it [looks like this](http://mattgibsonphoto.com/) at the moment. The background stays the same size when zooming in the browsers I've tried. Though it wouldn't surprise me if Internet Explorer couldn't cope with it.

As to how *fast* the images on that site load, the trick is simply a good choice of compressible image, well-compressed. [The background that loaded when I visited their site](http://www.atomicdust.com/images/homebgs/JBS_9452.jpg) is 1024x680 pixels, but because it's mostly black and white with large areas of plain colour, it compresses down to a pretty tiny 74KB.

Comment: That List Apart article is great! Also your website looks pretty good mate I like it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It uses jQuery and this:

```
$.fn.bgResize = function(options) {

    var defaults = {  
        imageWidth: 800,
        imageHeight: 600
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var obj = $(this);

    var initHtml = obj.html();

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    obj.height(windowHeight);
    obj.width(windowWidth);
    $('#work-wrapper').height(windowHeight);
    $('#work-wrapper').width(windowWidth);

    obj.html('<div id="inner-bg">'+initHtml+'</div>');

    $('#inner-bg img').each(function(){
        $(this).css({'display' : 'block', 'width' : '100%', 'height' : '100%'})                              
    });

    function doResize(){

        var screenheight = $(window).height();
        var screenwidth = $(window).width();

        var imageheight = options.imageheight;
        var imagewidth = options.imagewidth;

        var ratio = imagewidth/imageheight;

        var testwidth = screenheight * ratio;
        var testheight = screenwidth / ratio;

        obj.height(screenheight);
        obj.width(screenwidth);
        $('#work-wrapper').height(screenheight);
        $('#work-wrapper').width(screenwidth);

        if (testheight < screenheight){
            obj.children('#inner-bg').width(testwidth);
            obj.children('#inner-bg').height(testwidth/ratio);
            var finalheight = Math.round(testwidth/ratio);
            var finalwidth = testwidth;
            var topoffset = (finalheight - screenheight)/2;
            var leftoffset = (finalwidth - screenwidth)/2;
        }

        else if (testheight > screenheight){
            obj.children('#inner-bg').height(testheight);
            obj.children('#inner-bg').width(testheight * ratio);
            var finalwidth = Math.round(testheight * ratio);
            var finalheight = testheight;
            var topoffset = (finalheight - screenheight)/2;
            var leftoffset = (finalwidth - screenwidth)/2;
        }

        else {}

        obj.children('#inner-bg').css("top", -topoffset);
        obj.children('#inner-bg').css("left", -leftoffset);

    }

    doResize();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        doResize();
    });


    return this;

};
```